# Existe alguma diferença entre a propriedade clip e overflow?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, html-tags

Estudando sobre a propriedade `clip` me deparei com a seguinte afirmação:

> A propriedade `clip` funciona de maneira parecida com `overflow`
>   com algumas diferenças.

Isso me gerou algumas duvidas:

- Essa afirmação é verídica?
- Quais seriam essas diferenças?
- Em que situação se aplica uma ou outra propriedade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A proriedade [`clip:;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) permite que você especifique um retângulo para recortar um elemento absolutamente posicionado. O retângulo é especificado em quatro coordenadas, todas começando do canto superior esquerdo do elemento a ser cortado.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Já a propriedade [`overflow:;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) especifica o que acontece se o conteúdo transborda a "caixa/*container*" de um elemento.

Esta propriedade quando especificada serve para adicionar barras de rolagem quando o conteúdo de um elemento é demasiado grande para caber em uma área especificada ou para cortar/limitar o conteúdo de uma caixa quando usado `overflow:hidden;` .

```
.elemento {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll; /* adiciona automaticamente uma barra de rolagem/scroll ao elemento se o conteúdo for maior, dando a possibilidade de fazer scroll para ver o resto do conteúdo */
}
```

> O único caso em que estas propriedades funcionam de forma semelhante é ao fazer uso do `overflow:hidden;` para recortar imagens como podes ver neste exemplo abaixo:

```css
.clipImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,500px,200px,0px);
}
.clipOverflow {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clipOverflow img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipOverflow">
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/1/624/32968186751_a913f86f82_c.jpg">
</div>

<img class="clipImg" src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/1/624/32968186751_a913f86f82_c.jpg">
```

Mas como podemos ver neste exemplo, enquanto o `clip` literalmente *clipou* uma porção da imagem, já no `overflow:hidden;` teríamos que trabalhar melhor o código para obter este mesmo efeito do `clip`, mas no final o conceito é o mesmo de utilizar o `overflow:hidden;` desta maneira. A imagem apenas se parece mais encaixada porque demos um `width:100%;` à imagem para respeitar a caixa/*container* *parent* `clipOverflow`.

Answer (score 6):

- **Essa afirmação é verídica?**

Não é não. Estas propriedades até tem uma relação entre si, mas controlam coisas diferentes.

- **Quais seriam essas diferenças?**

`clip:` permite especificar uma área retangular na qual uma imagem mais larga que o `container` deve ser cortada.

Note que a propriedade `position` deve ser `absolute` (posição absoluta).

Note também que esta propriedade não funciona se `overflow:visible`

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

`overflow:` especifica o que acontece quando o conteúdo transborda (overflow) a caixa do elemento que o contém. De acordo com o valor, a imagem pode ser cortada ou mostrar barras de rolagem.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

- **Em que situação se aplica uma ou outra propriedade?**

Você deve portanto, decidir quando usar uma ou a outra propriedade, ou mesmo as duas.

`overflow` vai dizer se corta ou não e `clip`como é feito o corte do conteúdo.

Além disso, como há restrições (no caso de `clip`), você deve ficar atenta a isso também. Ou acaba usando uma propriedade que é ignorada e você fica sem saber porque não funciona.